# How to add conditional statements in Format-Table

Tags: powershell

PowerShell script:

```
Get-Wmiobject -class Win32_logicaldisk -computername XXXXXXX -filter`
 "drivetype=3" | Sort-Object -Property DeviceID | Format-Table -Property DeviceID,`
 @{label='FreeSpace(MB)'; expression={$_.Freespace / 1MB -as `[int]}},@{label='Size(GB)'; expression={$_.Size / 1GB -as `[int]}},@{label='%Free'; expression={$_.FreeSpace / $_.Size * 100 -as [int]}}
```

output:

```
 DeviceID FreeSpace(MB) Size(GB) %
 -------- ------------- -------- -----
 C:               10139       99    10
 D:              258235      300    84
 E:               51098       50   100
 F:               41964       50    82
```

My question is if free space less than 15 %, this device line will show red.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `Write-Host` to specify the text color. 
First, convert the output of `Format-Table` into a simple string using `Out-String -Stream`. After that, specify the text color for each condition and display it on the screen with `Write-Host`.

```
Get-Wmiobject -Class Win32_LogicalDisk -ComputerName . -Filter "drivetype=3" |
Sort-Object -Property DeviceID | Format-Table -Property @(
    "DeviceID"
    @{ l = 'FreeSpace(MB)'; e = { $_.Freespace / 1MB -as [int] } }
    @{ l = 'Size(GB)';      e = { $_.Size / 1GB -as [int] } }
    @{ l = '%Free';         e = { $_.FreeSpace / $_.Size * 100 -as [int] } }

) | Out-String -Stream | ForEach-Object {
    Write-Host $_ -ForegroundColor ("White", "Red")[$_ -match "\d+$" -and [int]$Matches[0] -lt 15]
}
```

Comment: Hi Rokumaru,  the script is working fine. thank you very much , This is just what I need.